# Copying range from one sheet to matched range in another

Tags: excel, vba

My goal is for the user to fill in the table "InputOutput" on the InputOutput Log sheet. When an item is added to the table, the user inputting that item will first fill out columns A through D, and then will "sign off" on the entry in column E. A change to this worksheet, more specifically to column E, triggers my code (shown below) with the intent of matching the Rack, Box, and Vial Positions to the correct row on the tables in sheets "Rack1" and "Rack2". When an item is removed from inventory and the user "signs off" in column F, the code will also be triggered and clear the contents that were entered in that range previously. A log of everything that went in or out of inventory *must* be kept with the "sign off"s from the entry, so a query table is not an option.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim InOutTbl As ListObject: Set InOutTbl = ListObjects("InputOutput")
Dim InByRng As Range: Set InByRng = InOutTbl.ListColumns(5).DataBodyRange
Dim OutByRng As Range: Set OutByRng = InOutTbl.ListColumns(6).DataBodyRange
Dim MtchSheet As Worksheet, VialPos As String, MtchTbl As ListObject, MtchVialPos As Range, CopyRng As Range, PasteRng As Range
Set MtchSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Left(InOutTbl.Range(Target.Row, 1), 5))
VialPos = InOutTbl.Range(Target.Row, 2).Value
Set MtchTbl = MtchSheet.ListObjects(InOutTbl.Range(Target.Row, 1).Value)
Set MtchVialPos = MtchSheet.Cells.Find(What:=VialPos, after:=MtchTbl.HeaderRowRange(1), LookIn:=xlValues)
Set CopyRng = Range("C" & Target.Row & ":D" & Target.Row)
Set PasteRng = MtchSheet.Range("B" & MtchVialPos.Row & ":C" & MtchVialPos.Row)
If Not Application.Intersect(InByRng, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    CopyRng.Copy
    PasteRng.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
ElseIf Not Application.Intersect(OutByRng, Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
    PasteRng.ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

I have included the file for a simplified version of my sheet:

https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/2n46biqr4olg50slvvsgw/Simplified-Version-Inventory.xlsm?rlkey=of17zkngpt3aij89jj93ly47l&dl=0

This works for entering in a single item, row by row. I am wondering if it would be possible to run the macro for each of the rows where a cell was changed in column E or F by autofilling/pasting in multiple cells at once. For example, the user added items to all 10 Vial Positions of Rack 1 Box 1 and wishes to "sign off" in column E by AutoFilling (so they don't have to do it 10 times). Another example would be if the user removed all of those items and wishes to "sign off" in column F by Autofilling. Right now, the only range being copied/pasted is for the first row of the target range.

Comment: Are any removed vials always returned to the same location?  What prevents someone from logging samples into box positions that already have content? Or logging removal of non-existent vials?  I think you'd probably need a lot more code before you could rely on this.  It also might be better to have any updates applied more transparently - let the user select the rows to update and click a button to process the selected rows.

Comment: ...that way if there's a problem with any of the rows, they can correct the data and re-run the update.